# How i can Use deathbycaptcha in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, casperjs

I am developing CasperJS application and want to use deathbycaptcha in my script . i search in net but found nothing . the problem coming is i don't want to use php library . and there is no api for phantomJS . i found deathbycaptcha API for nodeJS but i want api for casperJS is there any way to do this if any one know how to do this please help .

NodeJs library : https://www.npmjs.org/package/deathbycaptcha

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own version. It doesn't look like much code to write though.

You will need to do the request completely in the page context, because phantom does not provide a request function like node. Then you will probably run into same origin issues, so you will need a second webpage instance to query deathbycaptcha.

Another approach would be to save the captcha as an image, invoke an existing node/python/php script for deathbycaptcha and then pass the result to the webpage instance.

Comment: Yes sir i tried to do node but i think i must do lotes of config .

Comment: Sir i have used other solution for my problem .Now i am using 2 browser in my script and i have fetch the data from other brower and what i want is to pass data from one browser to other browser


var shown ="";
Casper.then(function() {
  var num = 0;
 shown = this.evaluate(function isShown(k) {
    return document.getElementById("search_samplecaptcha_CaptchaImage").src
  }, num);
Casper.SmileCommon.LogMessage( "fsdfsdfdsfsdf"+ shown );

Casper.wait(6000 , function(){ 
});
});


Now i want this value in 
xyz.then(function(){
 var Here = shown; 
});

Comment: @user3705756 Please update your question accordingly. Don't forget to note what you have tried and what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) what run CasperJS/PhantomJS on nodeJS.

I have use deathbycaptcha(npm package) in my project with SpookyJS, for talk with nodeJS.

project intro:

> Drive CasperJS from Node.js.
>
> Note: If you are simply looking to control Phantom from Node and don't need Casper's API, have a look at PhantomJS 1.8, which has native WebDriver support.